# Availability of R packages on Raspberry Pi

Tags: software-installation, script

I couldn't find it by googling. Are all usual R packages from CRAN also available in R on Rasbian on Raspberry Pi? What is the current supported R version on Pi 4?

Answer (score 1):

At the default Raspberry Pi OS repository you will find for the `r-*` packages:

```
rpi ~$ apt-cache pkgnames 'r-' | wc --lines
764
```

From this 764 packages just install what you need. You will find the version in the package description for example in `r-recommended`:

```
rpi ~$ apt-cache show 'r-recommended' | grep '^Version:'
Version: 3.5.2-1
```